# when 'generating' a URL from first get request and redirecting, second get request does not get executed

Tags: node.js, express

When I land on the home page I add a query string to the URL and then I redirect to that URL.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

       let room = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
       console.log(room);
       res.redirect('/views/index.html?room=' + room);

})
```

but then i would like to access the query string from the other page but can't quite figure out why this is not working:

```
app.get('/views/index.html', (req, res) => {
       console.log('heu ' + req.query.room)
})
```

I've tried to change the path but nothing seems to be working.
Any help would be appreciated. :)

EDIT: full server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app);
app.use(express.static('./'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

       let room = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
       console.log(room);
       res.redirect(`/views/index.html?room=${room}`);

})

app.get('/views/index.html', (req, res) => {
       console.log('hey ' + req.query.room)

})
server.listen(1337, function () { });
```

server.js is in the main folder, then I have a sub-folder (views) containing the index.html page

Comment: Please edit your post to include the rest of your app.

Comment: there it is, I dont think the html will be necessary

Comment: Because you set `express.static()` before your other get handler, it will handle the request for /views/index.html.

Comment: so how should i change it in order to get the second handler to handle the second request?

Comment: What are you trying to do?